# How to plot displacement and acceleration from a piecewise velocity function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

Given a velocity function in piecewise form. The objective is to plot both the displacement `s(t)` and accelaration `a(t)`. I have no idea

- to use `Derive` when the function `v(t)` is in postfix form.
- whether there is a built-in PostScript macro to integrate.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\v{  
  u 1 lt { 1 }{ 
    u 3 lt { (2-(u)) I2P }{ 
    u 4 lt { -1  }{ 
    u 6 lt { ((u)-5) I2P }{ 
                        1 
                    } ifelse 
                    } ifelse 
                    } ifelse 
                    } ifelse 
}     
  

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{/I2P {exec AlgParser cvx exec} def}%
\foreach \f/\l in 
{
    {x /u ED \v\space Derive}/{a(t)},% it does not work!
    {x /u ED \v\space Integrate}/{s(t)} % it does not work!
}
{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(8.5,3.5)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1,-2)(8,3)[$t$,-90][$$,0]
  \psset{plotpoints=200,linejoin=1,strokeopacity=.5}%
  \psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt]{0}{7}{x /u ED \v}
  \rput(4,3.25){\textcolor{red!50}{$v(t)$}}
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{0}{7}{\f}
  \rput(2,3.25){\textcolor{blue!50}{$\l$}}  
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

The expected output (excluding the axes and any other trivial accessories) should look like the following screenshot generated with Mathematica.

[image]

Comment: Maybe specify your requirements better: Do you want/must use pgfplots or pstricks or ...

Comment: AFAIK there is no easy computer algebra system with Tex and Friends. I assume that one could use R or Python that integrates with LaTeX for such a task. But personally, I would calculate the needed data outside of LaTeX and just read the csv file or use the pre-calculated equations.

Comment: Ok, because you use a lot of other tags for your question.

Comment: That is ok but you could be clearer in explaining your restrictions/preferences. I try to help - nothing more.

Comment: Please, do not attack with `reputations`. :-)

Comment: The previous bounty expired and it automatically chose the winner beyond my control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Python's `matplotlib` and `pgf` this could be done pretty easily.

The Python script doing the calculations:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = 0.1 # time resolution
t = np.arange(0, 8 + dt, dt)
v = np.ones(t.size)
v[np.logical_and(t >= 3, t <= 4)] = -1
v[np.logical_and(t >= 1, t <= 3)] = -2 / 2 * (t[np.logical_and(t >= 1, t <= 3)]
                                              - 1) + 1
v[np.logical_and(t >= 4, t <= 6)] =  2 / 2 * (t[np.logical_and(t >= 4, t <= 6)]
                                              - 4) - 1

a = np.gradient(v, dt)
s = np.cumsum(v) * dt
s -= s[0]

plt.plot(t, v, label=r"$v(t)$")
plt.plot(t, a, label=r"$a(t)$")
plt.plot(t, s, label=r"$s(t)$")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel(r"$t$")

# save the resulting figure as PGF calls, if you use the file extension '.pdf'
# you'll directly get a PDF you could include in your document using
# `\includegraphics` (you would have to set up the RC-parameters to match the
# look of your document).
plt.savefig("velocity_displacement_acceleration.pgf")
```

The LaTeX file printing that into PDF:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\input{velocity_displacement_acceleration.pgf}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1: Nice and clean code.

Answer (score 2):

One could try to differentiate and integrate directly in tikz/pstricks/metapost. I am most familiar with metapost, so I give an example using it. For integration I simply use the Euler method. One could use more sophisticated methods, if needed. Since I use ConTeXt, the relevant code is wrapped into `\starttext\startMPpage` and `\stopMPpage\stoptext`.

```
\starttext
\startMPpage[offset=3bp,instance=doublefun]
n=500;
tmax=8;
myeps=epsilon;
path a,s,v;

v=((0,1)--(1,1)--(3,-1)--(4,-1)--(6,1)--(8,1));

% define v merely as a function of t
def vt(expr t) =
  ypart (v intersectionpoint ((t,-infinity)--(t,infinity)))
enddef;

% numerical differentiation
def dvdt(expr t) =
  (vt(t+myeps)-vt(t-myeps))/(2*myeps)
enddef;

a =  (0,dvdt(myeps)) -- 
    for i=1 upto n-1: 
     ((i/n)*tmax, dvdt((i/n)*tmax)) -- 
    endfor 
     (tmax,dvdt(tmax-myeps));

% numerical integration
z0 = origin;
for i=1 upto n:
x[i] = x[i-1]+(1/n)*tmax;
y[i] = y[i-1]+(1/n)*tmax*vt(x[i-1]);
endfor;

s = z0 for i=1 upto n: -- z[i] endfor;

pickup pencircle scaled 1bp;
draw v scaled 1cm withcolor darkblue;
draw a scaled 1cm withcolor darkgreen;
draw s scaled 1cm withcolor "orange";

pickup pencircle scaled 0.5bp;
drawarrow ((0,0)--(8.5,0)) scaled 1cm;
drawarrow ((0,-1.5)--(0,2.5)) scaled 1cm;

\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

[image: A plot showing v, a and s]

Some problems:

- The derivative contains (almost) vertical lines.
- The integral is not perfect. Look at the values at 4 and 6, where it is supposed to be zero.

Comment: Oh, many thanks for the bounty! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

- This is a **"work in progress"** (WIP).
- I try to use the free software [Scilab](https://www.scilab.org/) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab)) to numerically calculate the position and the acceleration based on a piece-wise defined velocity.
- Scilab could then output these values as a CSV file that can be read by `pgfplots` and friends/relatives.
- So far I got some problems, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059245) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69059832).

[image]